# in Python 3, can a superclass polymorphically call a subclass's constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

I want to create method (say `copy`) in a class (`Parent`) that will return an object of either the class *or the subclass* that invokes it. I want `type(x) == type(x.copy())`.

None of the approaches I tried were satisfactory.

- Using the superclass constructor returns the superclass (make senses but I figured it was worth a try).
- Creating a function `init_me` in each subclass that the super class uses but that defeats the purpose of inheritance.
- I started to explore `__new__` and `__init__`, but quickly decided Python must have a better way.

Sample code

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, p1=p1_default, p2=p2_default, p3=p3_default):
        ...   # common stuff
        self._special_suff()
    def copy_works_if_subclass_does_extra(self):
        return self.init_me()
    def copy_only_does_superclass(self):
        return Parent()
    def copy_with_init(self):
        return self.__init__()
    def whoami(self):
        print('I am just a parent')

class Dad(Parent):
    def _special_stuff():
        ...     # Dad special stuff
        return 
    def whoami(self):
        print('I am a dad')
    def init_me(self):
        return Dad()

class Mom(Parent):
    def _special_stuff():
        ...     # Mom special stuff
        return 
    def whoami(self):
        print('I am a mom')
```

Comment: `return self.__init__()` does not copy the object. It just recalls `__init__` on the same object. You should use `cls.__new__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to write a `copy` method in your base class that will still work when called on an instance of a derived class. This can be made to work, but it's only easy if your child classes only expect the same set of arguments as the base class. If their `__init__` method expects different arguments you'll need separate `copy` methods for each derived class.

Here's a quick example of how it can work. The trick is to call `type(self)` to get the right class, and then call the class with appropriate constructor arguments to get the new instance:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.attr1 = arg1
        self.attr2 = arg2
        self.attr3 = arg3

    def copy(self):
        cls = type(self)
        return cls(self.attr1, self.attr2, self.attr3)

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        super().__init__(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        self.some_other_attr = "foo"
```

In practice this tends not to work as well, since the `Derived` class will usually want to take an extra argument to set up its extra attribute. An option that might work in that situation is to use [the `copy` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) rather than writing your own `copy` method. The function `copy.copy` will be able to copy many Python instances without any special support.

Comment: The `cls = type(self)` followed by `return cls(...)` answers my question. My impression is that if I need to use `type`, then I need to reconsider my _design_.

Comment: I don't think using `type` is inherently bad design. There *are* some kinds of bad code that rely upon it (especially beginner code that does `if type(foo) == Bar` instead of using `isinstance`), but it is perfectly reasonable to use `type` when you need to deal with class objects along with their instances. It's one of Python's basic introspection tools.

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things a *lot*. Minimal example with a simple constructor implemented on the child class:

```
import copy

class Parent():
    def whoami(self):
        print('Just a parent')
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def copy(self):
        # Maybe copy.deepcopy instead
        return copy.copy(self)


class Dad(Parent):
    def whoami(self):
        print('I am a dad')
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.gender = 'Male'
```

You don't even need a constructor in Python if you don't need. Or you can have one on the superclass and nothing on the child.

Some usage:

```
>>> dad = Dad("Clark Griswold")
>>> dad.name
'Clark Griswold'
>>> dad.whoami()
I am a dad
>>> isinstance(dad, Dad)
True
>>> isinstance(dad, Parent)
True
>>> type(dad.copy()) == type(dad)
True
```

Comment: I am trying out a design approach that may be a dead end. The superclass constructor had several arguments. These arguments would be the same for all inherited classes.  So the idea is to have the subclasses implement a 'private' method use to do their specialized construction.  Polymorphic dispatch would handle the variations in the subclasses.  Then I realized a base function (more than just `copy` from the example) needed to return subtypes. **Over complicating?** Perhaps. But before changing the design, I wanted to check my options.

Comment: Could you include an example of the specialized construction in the original post. I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: My last comment was true, but misleading. The main challenge is the reuse of the `copy` function.  I want `Dad().copy` and `Mom.copy()` to use the same code in the superclass but in both cases return the subclass. So how to I make the superclass base code smart enough to use constructor of subclass?

Comment: I added a `copy` to the my example. Not exactly sure how yours will work.